# Google.apis.youtube.v3 xamarin.android Sample

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, youtube, youtube-api

basically i need to play a youtube live stream
i will use the Google.apis.youtube.v3 because it's the best solution i found.
i need a lot of the features offered there so a solution like use iframe won't serve me...
i'm using xamarin.android so the ios solution is not needed for now
The Google.apis.youtube.v3 on xamarin i don't seem to find any code sample that have a video player

expected solutions are:
a link to a sample code that contains how to play a video/livestream
some sort of instruction about how to play a video/livestream... i found the packages classes at 
https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3/latest/api/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.html
but i'm not sure about how to use it
i'm still a newbie so please go easy on me :)

Comment: I think this should serve your purpose https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet

Comment: i saw the is page but all it have is not related to playing a video

Comment: Umm I think the NuGet has xamarin support so you should be able to use all the API's https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3/

Comment: i did not understand what do you mean when saying "be able to use all the API's" nor when you said "NuGet has xamarin support"

Comment: @FreakyAli Furthermore the Link you sent first is a console Application so you can't add a video into it

Comment: You have to setup your credit card to get Google API credentials to use Youtube on your phone unless you just put a bunch of web views. I tried to do something similar without needing any API keys, you can check the code here https://github.com/saamerm/XF-YouTubeChannel-Streaming

Comment: What did you end up using

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. the account part i already completed so there is no problem there. the web views are bad because 1. you don't have controls like (fullscreen, autoplay, etc.)  2. the <iframe> embedding is being disabled for the non-monetized channels so i cannot use this solution any way. i will be looking into the link you provided immediately Again sorry for the late reply

Comment: well the solution you provided is <iframe> so i won't be using that. i will keep you updated on whatever i find at the end